# jQuery Events Working, Normal JS Events Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dom-events, jquery-events

I'm running into a strange issue with event handling in JavaScript. Most of my events work fine using the following format:

```
var myCustomEvent = new CustomEvent('myEvent', {
    detail: {data: myData}
});
this.element.dispatchEvent(myCustomEvent);
```

Where `this.element` refers to an `element` variable within a custom object. This code would be called within one of that object's prototype functions. The corresponding event handler looks like this:

```
d3.select('#container').on('myEvent', function() {
    that.foo(d3.event.detail);
})
```

This handler takes place within a prototype function of a *different* object.

Again, this normally works fine, however, I've run into a few places where that code doesn't work. The event never triggers the handler. In fact, the only way I've managed to get the event to register with the handler is to use jQuery:

```
$(this.element).trigger('myEvent', [{data: myData}]);
```

With event handler:

```
$(d3.select('#container').node()).on('myEvent', function(e, data) {
    that.foo(data);
})
```

I realize this isn't really a reproducible example, but I'm wondering if anyone has run into something like this before or has any ideas as to what the problem could be.